# Get nested data set with all repeated records satisfying condition

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a following structure in a BigQuery table:

```
make        STRING    NOT NULLABLE
feature     RECORD    REPEATED
  name      STRING    REQUIRED
```

The following query returns all data where at least one `feature` record satisfies condition `length(f.name) = 5`:

```
select * from tbl t, t.feature tf
where length(tf.name) = 5
```

How do I get only data where ALL `feature.name` records satisfy the above condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try [subquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning_for_values_that_satisfy_a_condition):

```
select * from tbl t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from unnest(t.feature) AS tf
    where length(tf.name) != 5
)
```